# Projection onto $\mathbb{R}$ of Borel subset is Borel

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

I am finding on the internet that the following is an impossible problem, yet, it is one of my homework problems.

For some fixed $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that if $A$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ then $A(y) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : (x,y)\in A\}$ is Borel.

As I said, the problem is that I keep reading online that this is actually not true. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a projection but a "section" of $A$ and these are Borel:

The map $f_y:x \to (x,y)$ is a homeomorphism between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R \times \{y\}$ and
$A(y)= (f_y)^{-1}[A \cap (\Bbb R \times \{y\})]$ is thus Borel.

The projection of $A$ is $\{x \in \Bbb R: \exists y \in \Bbb R: (x,y) \in A\}$, which is in general an analytic set, and need not be Borel. The point is that we fix $y$ here, so we don't get "uncountable quantification".

Comment: If I want to constructively prove it, how could I do that? I always have trouble proving something is Borel, is this the same as proving it is Borel measurable?

Comment: @TheBosco this is a constructive proof.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to say is that this depend on the fact that the homeomorphism keeps the Borel property of the set. How can this be proven?

Comment: @TheBosco that’s trivial as continuous functions are Borel measurable.

Comment: There's a minor detail that should perhaps be noted: one should verify that when $A$ is Borel in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $A \cap (\mathbb{R} \times \{y\})$ is Borel in  $\mathbb{R} \times \{y\}$ (that is, it is in the $\sigma$-field generated by the open sets of the subspace topology on $\mathbb{R} \times \{y\}$).   It is not hard, but important to the validity of the proof.

Comment: @NateEldredge I assumed the OP would know that. It's an easy consequence of the definition of the subspace topology. Or define $f_y$ to be just continuous from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^2$ and then we have a simple intersection of plane Borel sets, and then using Borel-measurability of $f_y$ only.